# C++ Runtime Error when Debug in VS 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, runtime-error, devenv

I use VS 2008, win xp.

Now, when I debug a Winforms app, in a click eventof an button, I get this error:

Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library
Runtime Error!

Program: C:\Program files...

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way....

If I install my application using msi, all is work
If I try devenv SafeMode all is work.

How can I get more information about it?

update: I use DependencyWalker for devenv.exe

Only DWMAPI.DLL not found

Few days ago, I re-install Office 2010. but reboot.

Comment: Seen this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215842/what-is-microsoft-c-visual-runtime-library-runtime-error-and-how-can-i-capt

Comment: I use C#, the question uses C++ commands...

Comment: That message comes from a C++ runtime library, so there's definitely some C++ code that malfunctions. Maybe it's some middleware.

Comment: I need get more information in any logs or registry... I dont know

Comment: Did you use empty project template or you've chosen some specific

Comment: I have solution with several projects. Fails when debug a Winforms project.